# Как ограничить количество метрик в памяти прометея 2.27 >

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

Всем привет.
Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что запускаю прометей (2.27) в кубере, и через некоторое время приходит оом киллер и гасит его потому что в памяти слишком много метрик.
пробую ограничить время хранения через ключи storage.tsdb.retention.time и storage.tsdb.retention.size но прометей все равно собирает и хранит больше метрик, чем ему сказано при запуске.
сталкивался ли кто с такой проблемой и как эту ситацию можно полечить, не накидываю дополнительную память на инстанс прометея.

прометей:
https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/2.27/storage/

кубер:
1.8

хельм чарт для прометея:
prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack

Comment: А «слишком много» это сколько конкретно?

Comment: больше чем памяти, которая выделена под прометей

Comment: Это сколько конкретно?

Comment: конкретные цифры разные, в зависимости от тачки\пода\назначения прометея. да и зачем они